# Visual Studio 2013 Team Explorer is not working

Tags: tfs

Having installed VS 2013 Premium Update 4 on my VDI going along with Team Explorer for VS 2013 and TFS 2013 Power Tools Update 2 there is a problem with missing Team Explorer extension. While opening VS error occurs as on attached screenshot:

[image]

Honestly I have no idea, what causes the problem. I tried to reinstall VS, TFS and several oder hints like clearing Team Explorer cache folder. With no result. And it seems to be VS problem, because from command line I can call TFS and my workspaces are listed properly, so It is installed for sure. As a clue there is kind of error, which occurs while opening solution, and 2 from event viewer:

[image]

[image]

[image]